# #<Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)>

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I get the following error, when trying to generate an app.

I have a database.yml with my db login info, but not sure what this error is exactly.  Does anyone know what it is?

I assume it is verify login to the test db.

Comment: you don't have the correct user/pw set up to connect to your mysql db

Comment: Thats what I thought. hmmm... ok.

Comment: Can you connect using: mysql -u root or do you need a password as in mysql -u root -p? If you need a password, then check your database.yml and make sure you actually have the username and password specified. In fact, how bout pasting your development settings from you database.yml here if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your db username and password are configured for the `development` environment, not just the `test` environment. Initial rails application setup is there.

The `test` database is used by tests, such as `rake spec` or `rake test` and the `development` database is used when you are working with rails such as `rails generate` or `rails console`.

A typical setup is below:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: foo_development
  pool: 5
  username: db_username
  password: db_password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: foo_test
  pool: 5
  username: db_username
  password: db_password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I have set for development, I think the issue that it needs a root user with no password.

Comment: It doesn't need that, it is just the default. Changing `config/database.yml` is how you override the default.

Comment: You are right, but for this specific app you can not change then database.yml, it requires root user/no PW.  Thanks

Comment: Then the problem is that your mysql instance has a password set for root. see if `mysql -u root` works.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to have root user access your application?

It's recommended you create a different user and grant all privileges to this user and then configure your database.yml with those credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to contribute my answer to this.
It sounds kind of amateur but it may help some poor chap that had the same issue as me.

I had my password in `database.yml` configured like this:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_name
  username: my_username
  password: !?my_password913
```

It's a rookie mistake but it screwed me up for a few minutes.
Ensure you wrap your password with quotes if you use special characters because ! for instance would evaluate as a boolean expression of false which would make `mysql2` ignore the password field and send `password=no`

Thanks!